# How to round up in C with casting?

Tags: c

```
include <stdio.h>
include <math.h>

int main() 
{
  int inches;
  float feet, cm, yard, meter;

  printf("Enter value <Unit: inches>:");
  scanf("%d", &inches);

  printf("Convert into *\n");

  feet = inches/12;
  cm = inches * 2.54;
  yard = inches/36.0;
  meter = cm/100;

  printf("====================\n");
  printf("feet\t:%6.2f\n", feet);
  printf("cm\t\t:%6.2f\n", cm);
  printf("yard\t:%6.2f\n", yard);
  printf("====================\n \n");
  printf("총 %dinches are %dm and %dcm.", inches, (int) round (cm/100), (int) cm%100);
}
```

Sorry, I didn't know how to enter in the code properly. I want to round the last "(int) cm%100" part up because C casting turns it into an integer and it rounds down. How would I round this up? It doesn't show on the post but I did include math.h and stdio.h

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, downvote converted to upvote.

Comment: its okay, that can happen haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(int) cm % 100` is grouped as `((int) cm) % 100`, which truncates `cm`. Compilation of `cm % 100` would fail since `%` requires integral arguments in C.

Use `fmod(cm, 100)` to extract the floating point modulus, and `round` the result. Both functions are in `math.h`, i.e.

```
(int)round(fmod(cm, 100))
```

is the fix.

But, that said, you might find that `(int)round(cm) / 100` and `(int)round(cm) % 100` return more sensible output insofar that `100cm` is no longer possible.

Finally, check the behaviour for negative input, which personally I'd disallow.

Comment: thank you, that fixed it. Although I have another following question. when I use fmod  functions and enter in 118 inches for the problem, it gives me 2m and 100cm. is there a way to fix that to just 3m and 0cm?

Comment: @raiN: Sure, round `cm` first in both expressions: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! you solved all the problems for me! thank you!!

Comment: Instead of `(int)round(...)`, consider `lround(...)`.